# ExtJs - how to create a new record with associations?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have two differents, but similar, models with the same associations, when I try to create a new record from one of these similar models, it does not 'copy' associations.

I have the same associations in both models.

```
record_updated = Ext.create('Suite.model.ProjTask', record.getData(true))
```

my record.getData(true) object:

[associations in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPs54.png)

and the new record_updated object:

[without associations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yV6sm.png)

Comment: Please try whether it works using `record.clone()` or `record.copy()`. They provide these functions for a reason, I guess.

Comment: but my records are of different models. record_updated (Suite.model.ProjTask) and record (Suite.model.ProjTaskGantt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround: set the associations records manually

```
record_updated.associations.each(function(association) {  
  if (typeof record.getAssociatedData()[association.instanceName] != 'undefined') {
    record_updated[association.instanceName] = Ext.create(association.model, record.getAssociatedData()[association.instanceName]);
  }
});
```